# Android Gigya Facebook Login unauthorized user error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, gigya

I am Integrating [Gigya](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android) with my android app for social login. All other social logins are working properly except Facebook.
With Facebook app installed on the device , if I try to login with Facebook from Gigya, It is always giving Unauthorized user with error code 403005.

I have registered my app in [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com). If I use the registered facebook APP Id in normal android app with facebook login integration it is working fine.

Is it an issue with Gigya or am I missing something with facebook registration.?

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android#Android-AddingFacebookNativeLogin for instructions configuring Facebook native login.